# How to delete the current profile Image while uploading the new image of a authenticated user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to delete the existing profile image( named as profile_pic in models.py) while uploading the new profile pic of a authenticated user..

Below is the code samples of views.py , forms.py and models.py

How to implement the functionality to delete the existing image while uploading new one in views.py or forms.py

Note : Please don't use function based views

views.py

```
class UpdateUserProfilePic(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    form_class = forms.UserProfilePicUpdateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('test')

    def get_object(self):
         return self.request.user
```

---------x--------------------------------------------

forms.py

```
 class UserProfilePicUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('profile_pic',)
```

---------x--------------------------------------------

models.py

```
   class User(AbstractBaseUser):
         .......
         .......
         profile_pic = models.ImageField(
                   upload_to='profile_pics',
                   default='default-profile.png')
         .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question I should note something, with your current code if user1 uploads a file named `image.png` then user2 upload another file with same name then user1 profile_pic will show profile_pic for user 2, to solve this problem you should replace `upload_to='profile_pics'` with a function and return a full path for upload path :-)

And here I give you 3 solutions for your question:

1. in your new `upload_to` function always return a constant value for each user (for example `hash of user id` - use `hashids`) so when user uploads a new picture it will be replaced with their previous picture
2. ignore the problem and let there be some unused profile pics in your project, after a while if you think this caused a problem get a list of profile_pics from your db then delete files which are not in that list
3. In `UserProfilePicUpdateForm` override `save` and in that code delete old picture (something like this)

   ```
   class UserProfilePicUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
       def save(self, commit=True):
           profile_pic =  User.objects.get(pk=self.instance.pk).profile_pic
           instance = super().save(commit)
           if profile_pic != instance.profile_pic:
               # delete old pic
   ```

Comment: Getting this error :              AttributeError at /accounts/profilepic/
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: sample code was just an abstract snippet to show you the general idea, it needs some changes to work

Comment: The pseudo code you provided helps me a lot.. Thanks aliva